# Library is for EM_AARCH64 (183) instead of EM_X86_64 (62): how to solve?

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, apk, cross-compiling

I have a JNI library file named libNativeExecutor.so compiled on Linux with the cross compiler package g++-aarch64-linux-gnu. When I'm trying to load this library on my Android application I get this error:

`W/System.err: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/~~tGBbxt4GYWkE9Ks3RTXqXA==/org.rg.rgservices-3J3N3egX_IhRgczwOEapfw==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64/libNativeExecutor.so" is for EM_AARCH64 (183) instead of EM_X86_64 (62)`

I believe that I use the wrong compiler: so which compiler package I should install and use?

Comment: You should build with the Android NDK toolchain as: (a) it will output all the necessary different platform libraries (up to 4 of them) and (b) Android uses a modified `libc` which you need to use. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides .

Comment: To elaborate on what @RichardCritten said, it looks like you're running in the simulator, which will use x86_64 as its arch (i.e. the host platform of the sim). You need to build this library for every arch required, including the sim if you're planning to test there. The aarch64 binary will be used on target.

Comment: Ok, so I should create a native project for the library and compile it with NDK toolchain